# Grails - include id property when calling .properties

Tags: grails, groovy

I'm trying to get all properties of domain objects as a Map, and found out that Grails provides built-in access to that through the `properties` field. However, I noticed that it ignores `id` property. Is there a way to force it to return `id` just like any other object properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to achieve this by using the Groovy JDK method [`Object#getProperties`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#getProperties%28%29).